# Looping change listening and counting loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

**EDIT 20.01.2020** ---  **NEW PROBLEM**

**Problem/principle of operation:**

1. I have tables, divided into X rows and Y columns. In creating the table uses Razor syntax for ASP.NET Core.
2. In the table I have to make a mathematical equation giving me the differences of two inputs with type = "time" (max 23:59), and quickly write this difference to the another input.

**I am early calculating by:**

Notes:

1.this references the html code below

```
  var elements_s = document.getElementsByClassName("forUser1");
  var elements_e = document.getElementsByClassName("forUser2");


 for (var i = 0; i < elements_s.length; i++) {
        elements_s[i].addEventListener("change", function (e) {
            document.getElementById("actual_1").value = diff_1();
                           // (---- few lines code later)
            document.getElementById("actual_31").value = diff_31();
        });
    }


 for (var i = 0; i < elements_e.length; i++) {
        elements_e[i].addEventListener("change", function (e) {
            document.getElementById("actual_1").value = diff_1();
                          //  (---- few lines code later)
            document.getElementById("actual_31").value = diff_31();
        });
    }

// I have these diff functions from diff_1 to diff_31

  function diff_1() {
        start = document.getElementById("start_1").value;
        end = document.getElementById("end_1").value;

        start = start.split(":");
        end = end.split(":");
        var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
        var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
        var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
        diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
        var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
        return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
   }
```

**one of the answers that has improved it**

1. This code works only when the inputs are first in the table and the resulting input is next to them
2. it doesn't work in my case

```js
function diff (start, end) {
  start = start.split(":");
  end = end.split(":");
  const startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
  const endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
  let diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const classList = e.target.classList
  if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')) {
    //retrieve the associated inputs
    const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
    const [start, end, actual] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('input')]
    const value = diff(start.value, end.value)
    actual.value = value
  }
})
```

```html
<table>

<tr class="day"> 
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="text"></td>
  <td class="forUser1"><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1"></td>
  <td class="forUser2"><input type="time" class="end"  id="end_1"></td>
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
  <td class="forUser3"><input type="time" class="actual"  id="actual_1" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr class="day">
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="text"></td>
  <td class="forUser1"><input type="time" class="start"  id="start_2"></td>
  <td class="forUser2"><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2"></td>
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
  <td class="forUser3"><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_2" readonly></td>
</tr>


</table>
```

**EDIT**

Notes:

1. I have to edit the code, I updated the html code above
2. I gave only 2 cases, ultimately I have over 30 cases
3. sorry for the wrong question asked before

Comment: There are a lot of inputs (of type time) in every tr now... what are the input which should be taken to compute the diff? the one with class start and end?

Comment: @grodzi class="start" and class="end" to class="actual". Others I wrote to show what the code looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your original sample code is correct, that is you want to compute diff with input whose id are `start_x` and `end_x` (`x` being some number), notice that only those inputs have respectively class `start` and `end`.

1. To select them in particular, you may use the css selector
   `'.start,.end,.actual'` (or eventually `'input.start,input.end,input.actual'`)
2. Your diff should just take two input nodes (or even just two string, which feels better since you could then test it without having to care about the DOM)

   ```
   function diff(strA, strB){
     //guess what
     return str
   }
   ```
3. Use the DOM which is already grouping your inputs:

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('.start,.end')].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
     //retrieve the associated inputs
     const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
     const [start, end, actual] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('input')]
   })
   ```
4. Instead of binding an event to every input, delegate it to the table

   ```
   document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
     const classList = e.target.classList
     if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')){

       //retrieve the associated inputs
       const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
       const [start, end, actual] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('input')]
     }
   })
   ```

Updated code with copy pasted diff which you still have to debug

```js
function diff (start, end) {
  start = start.split(":");
  end = end.split(":");
  const startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
  const endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
  let diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const classList = e.target.classList
  if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')) {
    //retrieve the associated inputs
    const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
    const [start, end, actual] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.start,.end,.actual')]
    const value = diff(start.value, end.value)
    actual.value = value
  }
})
```

```html
<table>

<tr class="day"> 
<td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
<td class="forUser0"><input type="text"></td>
  <td class="forUser1"><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1"></td>
  <td class="forUser2"><input type="time" class="end"  id="end_1"></td>
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
  <td class="forUser3"><input type="time" class="actual"  id="actual_1" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr class="day">
<td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
<td class="forUser0"><input type="text"></td>
  <td class="forUser1"><input type="time" class="start"  id="start_2"></td>
  <td class="forUser2"><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2"></td>
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
  <td class="forUser0"><input type="time"></td>
  <td class="forUser3"><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_2" readonly></td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: is it possible to refer to a specific table? because I'm currently reading the first table from the page

Comment: @blackZombie Normally ```querySelector('table')``` should return the first table matched. If you want to be explicit you can still enforce ```querySelector('table:first-child') ```

Comment: unfortunately I had to update the question in my case, but when the inputs are more side by side this script does not work, sorry for the problem

Answer (score 0):

Creates an an array of elements.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
```

Iterate and log each item.

```
for (var i = 0, total = elems.length; i < total; i++) {
  var item = elems[i];
  console.log('item', item)
}
```